# How to get the solution of sum of exponential?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I have an equation of the form: for $i\neq j$, $b_i\neq b_j$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_ke^{-xb_k}=0.
$$

I would like to get $x$. How to proceed? For $n=2$, the problem is fairly easy. I am interesting in the special case: $n=3$, and $a_3=-a_2-a_1$.
$$
a_1e^{-xb_1}+a_2e^{-xb_2}-(a_1+a_2)e^{-xb_3}=0.
$$

Comment: Any relation between the $b$s

Comment: You could write a polynomial in $y=e^{-x}$, solve it and then find $x=ln(y)$?

Comment: No there is no relation between $b_k$.